# Como instalar somente o autoload e rotas de laravel em um novo projeto?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-rotas, lumen

Estamos fazendo um teste com um novo projeto para um site de alto tráfego (algumas centenas, ou milhares,  de usuários por segundo) e queria saber se existe alguma maneira de instalar somente o sistema de rotas e autoload do laravel. Não vamos precisar de todos os módulos que vêm com ele, inicialmente. Alguma versão mais leve ou alguma maneira para desinstalar via composer o que não será usado. Em outras palavras precisamos da configuração mínima de MVC para esse framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uso o microframework desenvolvido a partir do Laravel, e mantido pela mesma equipe: Lumen  - https://lumen.laravel.com/

Comment: Ele possui somente o sistema de roteamento?

Comment: Não, ele vem principalmente com o roteamento ativado, mas você pode com um pouco de configuração usar algumas outras funcionalidades do Laravel como Eloquent, Blade, etc .. mas somente se necessário. Seria algo um pouco diferente do que você sugeriu, não irá retirar o que não necessita e sim adicionará somente o que necessitar e quando.

Comment: eu não preciso de todas as funcionalidades somente do sistema de roteamento e direcionamento para os controllers.